# Issue in calling the base class methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am newbie in Python.I know this question is useless.But I am frustrated with my issue.I have 2 methods defined in my base class `Animals`.When I try to call the base methods in my inherited classes it shows these error:
`NameError: name 'display_name' is not defined`

```
class Animals():
    def display_name(self):
        print ('Name is Mr.X')        
    def display_age(self):
        print('Age is 25')    
class Name(Animals):
    display_name(self)
class Age(Animals):
    display_age(self)

n=Name()
a=Age()
n.display_name()
a.display_age()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer to the `display_name` function with a `self` prefix instead of passing `self` as an argument.

Also, as noted by Antimony, you need to call the `display_name` from within a function that is associated with an instance of the class (inside a function that accepts the `self` argument).

Code that appears outside a method function but inside a class is associated with the whole class, not with any particular instance of that class - using the `self` variable in this context has no meaning - if you create multiple objects from the class which one does it refer to?

```
class Animals():
    def display_name(self):
        print ('Name is Mr.X')

    def display_age(self):
        print('Age is 25')    

class Name(Animals):
    def call_display_name(self):
        self.display_name()

class Age(Animals):
    def call_display_name(self):
        self.display_age()

Name().call_display_name()
```

Comment: Also, you're trying to call it in the class scope, rather than on an instance. Probably won't work out too well.

Comment: @codebox I got it.May you explain why i need to put the method call inside another method in derived class

Comment: I've tried to explain a little more in the answer, but you should probably read up a around the difference between class and object methods.